# Using sbt to run Play framework with angular 2 and with webpack

Tags: scala, angular, playframework, webpack, sbt

I'm new to all of the above and I know its possible to run angular 2 with sbt and Play. I'm using this [github project](https://github.com/joost-de-vries/play-angular2-typescript) as a guide and trying to incorporate webpack. I'm only using sbt ~run therefore I don't want to use activator to run the project. I am also using this [sbt-play-webpack plugin](https://github.com/stonexx/sbt-play-webpack). I'm getting the following error:

```
[info]                 Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
[info] javascripts/bundle.js  6.17 kB       0  [emitted]  main
[info]              main.map  2.56 kB       0  [emitted]  main
[info]     + 1 hidden modules
[info]
[info] ERROR in ./app/assets/app/main.ts
[info] Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'source-map-support'
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing any config files. So far, I have package.json, webpack.config.js, tsconfig.json, plugins.sbt and build.sbt. Am I missing something?

webpack.config.js file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const WebpackCleanupPlugin = require('webpack-cleanup-plugin');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');



module.exports = {
//context: path.join(__dirname, '/assets'),
entry: {//changed this by RADHA
    'main': './app/assets/app/main.ts'
},
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/public/bundles'),
    publicPath: '/assets/bundles/',
    filename: 'javascripts/bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map'
},
plugins: [
    new WebpackCleanupPlugin(),
],

devtool: 'source-map',


resolve: {

    extensions: ['.ts', '.js' ],
    modules: [ path.resolve(__dirname, process.env.NODE_PATH) ]
},

module: {
    loaders: [
      // .ts files for TypeScript
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: [
          'awesome-typescript-loader',
          'angular2-template-loader',
          'angular2-router-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
},
node: {
    global: true,
    crypto: 'empty',
    __dirname: true,
    __filename: true,
    process: true,
    Buffer: false,
    clearImmediate: false,
    setImmediate: false
}


};
```